# Make emails produced by query active links

Tags: php, hyperlink

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY company_name");

echo "<center><table border='1px' style='font-size: 12px;'>
<center><tr>
<th>Contact Email</th>
</tr></center>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['contact_email'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table></center>";
```

I need for the email addresses to be printed out as links so that users can just click on the email address to start an email. Is this possible?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2):

you can do this by

```
echo  "<td><a href='mailto:".$row['contact_email']."'>".$row['contact_email'] ."</a></td>";
```

**Note**

1. The entire **`ext/mysql`** PHP extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix mysql_, is [officially deprecated as of PHP v5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php) and will be removed in the future. So use either `PDO` or `MySQLi`

**Good read**

1. [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli/13944958)
2. [PDO Tutorial for MySQL Developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)
3. [Pdo Tutorial For Beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189)

Comment: That worked perfectly. I tried something similar but must not have had the syntax right. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Nothing magical about it...

```
echo <<< EOL
<td><a href="mailto:{$row['contact_email']}">{$row['contact_email']}</a></td>

EOL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
echo '<td><a href="mailto:' . $row['contact_email'] . '">' . $row['contact_email'] . '</a></td>';
```

Comment: Be careful of your quotes.  I fixed it for you :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an email link:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again">
```

Answer (score 1):

That would be something like:

```
echo "<td><a href='mailto:" . htmlspecialchars($row['contact_email']) . "'>" . htmlspecialchars($row['contact_email']) . "</a></td>";
```